# Difference between two dates with start date after end date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am currently using the following function to calculate difference between two dates using momentjs:

```
function calculateWorkdays(startDate,endDate) {
// + 1 cause diff returns the difference between two moments, in this case the day itself should be included.

const totalDays = moment(endDate).diff(moment(startDate), 'days') + 1;
const dayOfWeek = moment(startDate).isoWeekday();
let totalWorkdays = 0;

for (let i = dayOfWeek; i < totalDays + dayOfWeek; i++) {
    if (i % 7 !== 6 && i % 7 !== 0) {
      totalWorkdays++;
    }
  }
  return totalWorkdays;
}
```

The function works perfectly if the startDate is before the endDate. However, my application requires it to accept the opposite as well - startDate to be after endDate.

I am trying to alter the function so it outputs a negative number in the case explained above.

Example:

```
startDate = 2019-12-05
endDate   = 2019-12-03
result of function = -3
```

So far I have tried to swap startDate and endDate if startDate > endDate but this still results in a positive output of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flip the parameters if they're not in the expected order:

```
function calculateWorkdays(startDate,endDate) {
  if (startDate > endDate)
    return -calculateWorkdays(endDate, startDate);
  // rest of the code
}
```